# application_controller.rb or new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, convention, applicationcontroller

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, learning it to create a new SaaS I'm working on. Whilst I'm able to write some RoR, I don't know the majority of conventions for the language.

My question is, for the front website (seen by non-registered users) should I add the different page controllers to that, or create a new controller for example, `main` and extend that?

Whilst I'm at it, is there a page where I could read about the main conventions of Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preference is to add a new controller for the unrestricted part of the website. You could do it with a different page controller as well.

For learning about the conventions & about the tools and techniques of web development with rails, I strongly recommend Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial Book. It is available online for free, and the entire book can be seen as one one long page at http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial ;-)

Comment: Cheers Prakash, I'd like to learn a new language and the best practises as I go :)

Comment: That's definitely a good idea. Also, worthwhile to spend time on the tutorial book regularly over the next few months; the time invested repays itself very quickly.